# Comparison between series of two continuous monitor sampling the same parameter

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, equivalence

**Object**: understand if the series collected by two dirrerent continuous samplers on the same sample are equivalent.

**General description**: I have two different continuous monitors, determinating the real-time concentration of nitrates in freshwater (river environment). Monitors are perfectly syncronized and the probes are placed in the same point, so it can be assumed that they are monitoring the same water sample.  They collect for 24 hours one sample per minute, so at the end I have two series of paired data (1440 measures each).

**Important**: According to the distribution analysis, the two series are **not normally distributed**.

**Questions**:

1) Which are the most suitable tests to understand if the two instruments (or better the two series collected), could be considered equivalent or significantly different?

2)In case of a different parameter monitoring experience, with same features of above, but with two small series of paired data (ie two series of 24 hourly samples), test should be the same or not?